# How many sockets to create on the client side?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, thread-safety, iocp

I see some applications use multiple sockets. For example for chat they use unique socket and for file upload they use other socket etc. Why this process is needed when it can be done in one socket? is it because the way they handle the connection and open a new connection slot after each accept call?

I am working on IOCP chat application and i got confused by this scheme. If i want to handle the connections i make it 1 socket for each client but if client sending file there is no way for my server to allocate memory for the file upload because i do it after handling newly accepted connection so it gets complex to store the memory needed for files in memory pool specially for cleanup and memory freeing. Do i need to re allocate memory based on commands if i use 1 socket only in client side so the other buffers wont be overwritten? or the easiest way is to use 1 socket for each operation that takes much memory like file sending images etc so that my server will automatically allocates unique buffer for each new connection?

And when should i use CRITICAL SECTIONS in IOCP? in workers thread if i want to access buffer after i received some data then copy it to total buffer received. Do i need to enter critical sections before i copy from temp buffer to all buffer so that the other threads don't interference with the values?

Answer (score 0):

A listener socket on the server side creates a new socket each time there is a request from a client. At this point a new thread should be created to communicate with this client: it will deal with one-to-one communication with the given client. All the necessary resources should be allocated in this thread. On the client side you have one thread that deals with the server.

Comment: Create thread per connection is not recommended and does not scale very well. Thread creation has much overhead. My question was do i need to create more sockets for different operations on the client side? like file share image share text chat etc each one has it's unique socket so it will be asynchronous process.